# Using a button and a timer, have an annoying bug

Tags: macos, cocoa, timer

I'm using a button to activate a timer. In that button's code, it turns on the timer. I'll attach the code, though I doubt it'll make sense out of context.

```
- (IBAction)btnStartWasClicked:(NSButton *)sender {
if ([btnStartTitle.title isEqualToString:@"Start"])
{
    NSLog(@"Debug: Start button was clicked."); //Debug

    //Changes the Start button to say Stop
    [btnStartTitle setTitle:@"Stop"];

    started = TRUE;
    [self tick:nil];
    NSLog(@"Debug: Timer has started."); //Debug

    [btnReset setEnabled:FALSE];
    [btnLap setEnabled:TRUE];

    if (lapTimerIsPaused == TRUE)
    {
        lapTimerIsRunning = TRUE;
        [self tickAfterLap:nil];
    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Debug: Stop button was clicked."); //Debug

    //Changes the Stop button to say Start
    [btnStartTitle setTitle:@"Start"];

    started = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Timer has been stopped."); //Debug

    [btnReset setEnabled:TRUE];

    lapTimerIsRunning = FALSE;
    lapTimerIsPaused = TRUE;

    [btnLap setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I currently have a nasty bug I'm not quite sure how to get rid of. If the user double-clicks the start button really quickly, it will either:

A) Do nothing, just change the start button to say stop.

B) Make the timer count twice as fast (if the double-click is REALLY quick.) **THIS ONLY HAPPENS WHEN THE START BUTTON IS SET TO SAY STOP, NOT START.**

My bug is B. I'm not quite sure how to squash it.

Edit: The lap timer is a different timer than the regular timer, and I don't think the bug I'm having affects it, so ignore the lap timer code.

Any ideas?